# Can you make a jQuery call to WCF service using SOAP and WSHttpBinding?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, jquery, wcf

Can i make a JQuery call to WCF service using SOAP and WSHttpBinding?

If so, how? (any examples on the web?) If not, why not?

As you can see from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618629/jquery-wcf-soap-call-fail), i cannot get it to work.

I need to be able to use WSHttpBinding so i can support SAML and WS-Security. It is my understanding that basicHTTPBinding does not support ws-Security.

All other examples on SO either use json (which i can get to work easy) or basicHttpBinding.

I am required to use SOAP and ws-Security to comply with OGC 07-118r8 standards.

Comment: I think jQuery had become so popular that people are trying to do too many server side things on JS side. You need to define the boundaries and identify the lines that clearly separate the both worlds.

Comment: How would you call the web service then using javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With something like WS-* and the complexity of WCF, wouldn't it be easier to create a simple jQuery async callback to another page on your site that can leverage the .NET built-in WS-Security Libraries? From there you can fire off a call to the WCF endpoint, process the result, and return it back to the jQuery function as an easily readable response.

I found some articles that mention what you're trying to do. It sounds like you would essentially have to write your own WS-Security jQuery library before this would work straight from JavaScript (and I imagine that's probably impractical for you):

"A service exposed with “wsHttpBinding” binding implements WS-Security of WS-* family of web service specifications. As the binding uses security, the request will be rejected. The service cannot be called without implementing WS-Security at JQuery end. So, in order to call the service method, we have to compromise with the security."

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311908/Calling-WCF-service-exposed-with-different-binding

"...wsHttpBinding, which is a SOAP binding that won’t work with AJAX."

http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/jquery/jquerypart2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No way you can implement WS* in JavaScript!

Best option is to create another binding on the server and expose it as basic HTTP or even better as WCF REST.

Comment: Not an option... clients need to communicate with me via WS-*, not rest. We are required to follow a standard mentioned in my question.

Comment: So you wanna implement all that encryption in JavaScript? Well if you can, you will probably be rich since you will open up a lot of possibilities but I am not aware if such a thing has been done.

Comment: I see your point... so your saying Javascript client should call a local (unencrypted, but who cares because it's local?) WCF REST Web Service which in turn does the SAML authentication to the remote server via SAML/WCF SOAP?

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible in theory. I'm assuming for the moment you've figured out how to get your SAML token and deal with WS-Security.  WSHttpBinding defaults to soap 1.2, so either look at the http binding spec to figure out how to construct the request using jquery: http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part2/#soapinhttp or set EnvelopeVersion.Soap11 on WSHttpBinding.  good luck!

Comment: i have NOT figured out the SAML token part. I figured i'd better walk before running. So i wanted to get a basic service communicating. I'm new to WCF so i have not set any EnvelopeVersion.Soap11, but i will look into doing that. Thanks.

Comment: I would figure out the SAML/WS-Security part first because it's the bigger risk to the approach. I don't personally know for sure that it's feasible. A much easier approach would be to expose another WCF endpoint specific to js consumption and use that instead, as some others have suggested.